# Как можно реализовать такую анимацию пролистывания меню?

Tags: вёрстка, анимация

кто может подсказать чем сделали такую анимацию?
И тут элементы сделаны в 3d?
https://modus.moscow/menu/breakfast.php

Спасибо, просто впервые такую реализацию вижу))

Answer (score 2):

Там используется  вот эта библиотека http://www.fliphtml5.com

Но можешь конечно и свой велосипед писать, на кодепене что-то такое было, поищи по слову book

Answer (score 2):

На этой странице содержатся только 2д изображения. А подобное переворачивание происходит благодаря плагину 3D FlipBook или DearFlip для вордпресса.
Если интересен сам процесс анимации, то большая часть эффекта содержится в css анимациях:

```
transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) 
rotate(0deg)
```

И динамической смене `z-index` при развороте и все это приправлено огромным количеством кода Javascript, чтобы при наведении мышкой, производилось необходимое загибание страницы и при нажатии триггерились необходимые изменения выше указанных свойств